# Text overlapping in label whenever updating the label in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Whenever I am trying to update my label in the app, it is always overlapping the previous text. I don't know what is the mistake I am making for it to happen. If anyone knows please guide me.
here is the .py file:

```
import json
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Builder.load_file('rough.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    f=open('questions.json')
    global data
    data=json.load(f)
    def printing_questions(self):
        a=0
        question='Blue whale is a large animal'
        self.ids.question.text=''
        self.ids.question.text=question #i am changing text here, but it overlaps

class rough(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__=='__main__':
    rough().run()
```

Here is the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
<MyLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.width,root.height
        Label:
            id:question #in this label i am updating the text
            text:'Questions coming soon...444444444444442222222222222222ssssssssss\n555555555555211111assssssssss'
            multiline:True

        Button:
            text:'Next'
            on_release:
                root.printing_questions()
```

Comment: Would you please clarify the following, *'it is always overlapping the previous text...'*.

Comment: The text i am updating is coming over the previous text which was written. If the previous text was: my name is mordo, then the new text is coming over it and making it unable to read clearly the new text

Comment: what i want to achieve is that the previous text should be cleared when updating the label for new text

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are expecting. But if you want the text to wrap into its container (or, cease to overflow) you can modify its `text_size` property as,

```py
        Label:
            id:question #in this label i am updating the text
            text:'Questions coming soon...444444444444442222222222222222ssssssssss\\n555555555555211111assssssssss'
            halign: "center" # To set in the middle.
            text_size: self.width, None # Extends upto it's width.
```

Comment: Please see the above image you will understand what i am trying to tell @ApuCoder

Comment: Well I've no idea why that's happening ! May be it's due to the text renderer or provider or something else. I'll suggest to discuss/ look at kivy's blog (since its a new version, it may be a bug). If nothing works, submit this issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The previous text is:'Hello my name is mrsomethng' and when i update the label with:'What was the original color of ferrari models' they are both overlapping.
i want to show only the updated label not the previous text with it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).